Possible to setup veth with -n but not -b in systemd-nspawn?
making first experiments with systemd-nspawn.
I would like to set up a container to run a single application with isolation.
So far my command line is sudo systemd-nspawn -M mycontainer -x -U --user=me --as-pid2 plus some bind mounts. So far so good.
I also would like to have network isolation, since my application does not need to exchange data with the outside, but just to expose a single port to my own host.
It is unclear to me how to reach this goal: -p does not seem to work with ports on the loopback interface, so I think I need a veth. However, starting the container without -b, I cannot have networkd to configure my interface for me, nor I can configure it otherwise, because I am starting the container with an unprivileged user.
Any clue? Am I misinterpreting what I should be doing?
